# Custom Label does not work on Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customlabel, translation, language

I'm using custom label on lightning components, but it always shows me English, and does not follow the user language. Someone knows what to do in this case?

I've tried reference my custom label direct in visualforce pages and it shows perfectly in the user language, but when I put it in my lightning component it always appear in English language.

User Language used to test: Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese

Organization default language: Brazilian Portuguese

Updated with component and app markup

test.cmp

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL">
  {!$Label.c.MyLabel1}<br/>
  {!$Label.c.MyLabel2}<br/>
  {!$Label.c.MyLabel3}<br/>
</aura:component>
```

testApp.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL">
  <c:test/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Custom Labels are [supported in lightning components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_intro.htm). Can you post the component markup which is not working properly?

Comment: Updated @MarkPond.

Comment: Can you provide the organization language and the user language?

Comment: User Language used to test: Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese
Organization default language: Brazilian Portuguese

Comment: Is the translation workbench enabled in the organization?

Comment: Yes, translation workbench is already enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal implementation, English & Español & Português, demonstrating translation based on the language value set on the User record.

**App**

```
<aura:application access="global">
    <c:q228892 />
</aura:application>
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component access="global">
    {!$Label.c.MyLabel1}
</aura:component>
```

**Label Config**

[image]

**User Config - Español**

[image]

**Result Español**

[image]

**User Config - Português**

[image]

**Result Português**

[image]

**Result English**

[image]

Comment: Looks like my implementation, excepts that my master language is Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: You should also add the translation for your master language.

Comment: added the Portuguese example above

Comment: I was missing to add the translation for my master language as @RenatoOliveira said.  Even if I create the custom label for Portuguese I need to add it as a Translation for my custom label.